# Should I edit my older question, make a new one, or do nothing?

Tags: discussion, editing, too-broad

One of my earlier questions on Worldbuilding could have been written better, or split into several smaller questions. Would it be better to edit the question to better fit the general guidelines of the site, create a new question(or several questions breaking down the first question) or do nothing, leaving the question as it is?

The question in being [Everyday effects of telekinesis in a population](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/26397/everyday-effects-of-telekinesis-in-a-population)

In retrospect, I could have split it into several questions and stated it more clearly. I wouldn't want to make so many changes that the current answers are no longer accurate, but then if I asked it as a new question I'm not sure it would be different enough to justify asking it again. I may just be overthinking all of this, in which case it may be best to just leave it as is. If I could get some insight into this, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not edit your question. 7 months have passed, that's a long time.

You can as a new question, and you should focus on what wasn't answered in your first question. Asking a follow-up question is a good idea generally.

There you could ask a new question, and focus on what wasn't answered. You could ask a link to the previous question and explain, that although you had good answers, some points remained unclear. And thus ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

Don't edit in ways that invalidate answers, as others have said.

One approach to asking followup questions without them being closed as duplicates is to **explain what you've learned** from previous questions and then **build on that** in a new question.  I had [something like that](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/25318/28) -- that link is to the third in a series of related questions, each of which arose from the previous one (you can follow the links backwards in the questions).  That's not quite your situation (I didn't yet know I had all those questions at the beginning), but I link to it to illustrate a way of building on prior questions.  You, too, could ask new questions (several, it sounds like), starting from what you've already learned from your previous question and then refining them into new, focused questions.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that your question might have been better written in multiple posts and probably would have been closed as too broad if asked today.

I'd say you [should not edit a question to an extend that invalidates existing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148175/what-should-i-do-when-an-edit-would-change-the-context-of-a-question). But what you could do is enclosing on the topic as much as you can *without* invalidating the given answers.

Having a short look at your question and the answers, I'd say they did not really answer your second and third individual questions in detail:

> 2.How would this impact us if it were to happen in today's world?
>
> 3.How would this impact a more technologically developed society than our own?

The only exception is the second answer:

> **One thing I know: if this happened in today's world...**
>
> I wouldn't want to be holding stock in a spatula company.

Which is not a real in depth answer I'd say.

So in my opinion, you should try and narrow your question down as much as you can *carefully* and *without* invalidating the existing answers. Everything you edited out can then be asked as seperate question (if possible in a reasonable manner).